# fixture 'self' not found

Tags: python, appium, pytest

I'm new with Pytest-bdd. I'm trying to run a BDD test but I find always the same problem with the fixture. This is my code.I've tried without the @pytest.fixture and with only the step of @given gherkin step I get same result. fixture 'self'not found

```
import os
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import pytest
from pytest_bdd import scenario, given, when, then, parsers

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='module')
def Setup (self):
    "Setup for the test"
    desired_caps = {}
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

def Teardown():
    self.driver.quit()

@scenario('features.feature','Prueba1')
@given('step 1')
def test_single_player_mode(self):
    element1=self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.nestle.bagzielicious.beta:id/on_button_vegan")
    element1.click()
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: You might want to look at fixture's documentation to find its correct use. 

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html

Answer (score 1):

Usually those methods are all inside a class and then `self` refers to the class.

For example:

```
from unittest import TestCase


class DriverTestCase(TestCase):
```

Comment: Thanks to your fast reply. My problem is I don't know how combine the  Pytest-BDD with the unittest.If I put a class then the @given doesn't works.

Comment: Cannot you use Pytest?

Comment: The Idea is to use Pytest because amazon AWS farm works with this framework,  . Ithere aren't many resources on-line with appium and pytest-bdd

Answer (score 0):

Give the following code a try using Pytest:

```
import os
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import pytest
from pytest_bdd import scenario, given, when, then, parsers

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='module')
def driver():
    "Setup for the test"
    desired_caps = {}
    driver = webdriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
    yield driver
    driver.quit()

@scenario('features.feature','Prueba1')
@given('step 1')
def test_single_player_mode(driver):
    element1=driver.find_element_by_id("com.nestle.bagzielicious.beta:id/on_button_vegan")
    element1.click()
    sleep(1)
```